# Modular Architecture for Processing Pipeline

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I am trying to design the architecture of a system that I will be implementing in C++, and I was wondering if people could think of a good approach, or critique the approach that I have designed so far.

First of all, the general problem is an image processing pipeline. It contains several stages, and the goal is to design a highly modular solution, so that any of the stages can be easily swapped out and replaced with a piece of custom code (so that the user can have a speed increase if s/he knows that a certain stage is constrained in a certain way in his or her problem).

The current thinking is something like this:

```
struct output; /*Contains the output values from the pipeline.*/

class input_routines{
    public:
    virtual foo stage1(...){...}
    virtual bar stage2(...){...}
    virtual qux stage3(...){...}
    ...
}

output pipeline(input_routines stages);
```

This would allow people to subclass input_routines and override whichever stage they wanted. That said, I've worked in systems like this before, and I find the subclassing and the default stuff tends to get messy, and can be difficult to use, so I'm not giddy about writing one myself. I was also thinking about a more STLish approach, where the different stages (there are 6 or 7) would be defaulted template parameters.

Can anyone offer a critique of the pattern above, thoughts on the template approach, or any other architecture that comes to mind?

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to use a Lisp-family language for this type of project?

Comment: Oh, I most certainly want to use a Lisp-family language for this project, tragically, I'm adding functionality to an existing C++ imaging library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design is highly dependant on what the different stages actually do. I mostly prefer [pure virtual functions over non-pure virtual functions](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/abstraction-is-everything/) (abstract classes).

Common stages can be grouped together in abstract subclasses. By deriving from the main abstract class you still can still adjust every stage, but by deriving from a subclass you can reuse existing behavior which is already written. It tends to be less messy, as you mention for virtual methods.

If the different stages can also exist on their own (outside of the entire pipeline), also consider writing classes to seperate this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe create a list of functors in a factory, which implement the stages. Pseudo-code:

```
functorFactory() {
  return [ foo(), bar(), baz() ]
}
```

Users could reimplement the factory or just manipulate the list of functors. Pseudo-code

```
myFactory() {
  return [ foo(), myBar() ]
}
```

or

```
myFactory() {
  return functorFactory()[2] = myBar()
}
```

When setup is done, you can call each functor using the result of the last.

Comment: +1: this gives maximum flexibility, as the user is allowed to actually add steps / remove steps if they so wish.

Comment: That looks great, but how would I implement this in C++? I couldn't have an array of function pointers, since each function pointer would have a different type if the functions returned different things, and arrays can only hold objects of the same type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Monads as implemented in Haskell, that may give you a good idea on how to set things up. Haskell gets this type of thing really right.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a Intermediate type. All images would be converted into this format; each stage would take an Intermediate and return an Intermediate - *not* the same one, a new one.

A stage would be this:

`Intermediate DoSomething(const Intermediate &i);`

I usually avoid inheritance-based solutions in general unless they are a fairly obvious map onto the problem, e.g., objects in a 3D world.